# Pyspark filter dataframe if column does not contain string

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I hope it wasn't asked before, at least I couldn't find. I'm trying to exclude rows where Key column does not contain 'sd' value. Below is the working example for when it contains.

```
values = [("sd123","2"),("kd123","1")] 
columns = ['Key', 'V1']
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(values, columns)

df2.where(F.col('Key').contains('sd')).show()
```

how to do the opposite?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `~` as bitwise NOT:

```
df2.where(~F.col('Key').contains('sd')).show()
```